# Creating an associative array with keys from a simple indexed array of strings

Tags: php

I have an array of strings with a format of `key: value` like this:

```
Array
    (
         [0] => label: productlabel
         [1] => timezone: SDT
         [2] => price: 0.2225
         [3] => reserve: 60
    )
```

I need to create an associative array with the key part as the array element index and value part as the array element value, like this:

```
Array
    (
        [label] => productlabel
        [timezone] => SDT
        [price] => 0.22255
        [reserve] => 60
    )
```

Is there a shorter way or a function to create this, or I need to make it manually with basic control structures?

Comment: How are you creating the initial array with colon-separated values, easiest to change it at its source? Otherwise you'll have to use regex or explode to separate your values.

Comment: @ctwheels unfortunately this is how I receive the data from a Google spreadsheet. So changes at source is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each based on the : , then add to the new array

```
foreach($array as $value){   // loop the original array
  $split = explode(":",$value);  // split values based on : into 2 element array
  $array2[$split[0]] = $split[1];  // add to the new array, [key] = [value]
}
```

Comment: Accepted this because it works on php versions <=5.4

Comment: @neptune It's not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

[Map the array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) [splitting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the value on `:` and then use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to assign the values and keys from that split:

```
$originalArray = [
    'label: productlabel',
    'timezone: SDT',
    'price: 0.2225',
    'reserve: 60',
];

$newArray = array_column(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return explode(': ',$value);
        },
        $originalArray
    ),
    1,
    0
);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array and split in ':' after set the $key and $value.

```
$oldArray = [
    'label: productlabel',
    'timezone: SDT',
    'price: 0.2225',
    'reserve: 60',
];

$newArray = [];

foreach($oldArray as $pos) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $pos);
    $newArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the `:` to `=`, the strings are like .ini lines, so you could treat it like that.

```
$assoc = parse_ini_string(str_replace(': ', '= ', join("\n", $array)));
```